# If statement status dependent on dates (3 columns).TODAY() does not work

Tags: google-sheets

Hi all I have a situation where I have 3 columns which results in 3 results.

1. 3 columns are empty, display "0"
2. First column has a date <= today(), 2nd and 3rd column empty, result is "1"
3. First column has a date > today(), 2nd and 3rd column empty, result is "0"
4. Second column has a date and third column is empty (First col can be empty or filled), result = "2"
5. Third column has a date, result = "3"

Here is my code below:

```
=if(and(ISBLANK(A6), ISBLANK(B6), ISBLANK(C6)),"0",IF(and(A6<=NOW(), ISBLANK(B6), ISBLANK(C6)),"1",if(and(NOT(ISBLANK(A6)),B6<=NOW(), ISBLANK(C6)),"2",IF(C6<=NOW(),"3","0"))))
```

However I am getting mixed results, especially if the date in the first column is greater than the today's date, it shows up a result of "2" and not the expected "0"

Comment: Your sample formula and the text up top doesnt match - for example your saying today() in the description but you formula is saying now() and your description is saying as long as there is anything in B and C it should affect results but your formula is specifying  <= now() there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So despite your somewhat mismatched directives - here is a start - I am still unsure about which of your rules actually overrides - so when you updated that I will update the formula:

```
=if(counta(A1:C1)=0,0,IF(LEN(C1)>0,3,IF(LEN(B1)>0,2,IF(AND(LEN(A1)>0,COUNTA(B1:C1)=0,A1>TODAY()),0,IF(AND(LEN(A1)>0,COUNTA(B1:C1)=0,A1<=TODAY()),1,)))))
```

A couple things I am doing here:

Part of the reason your formula is having issues is two major things -

1) you need to reverse the order of your IF statements to allow the cells in C or B to trump the other rules, if that is the result you want. This way if you always want a 3 when anything is in column C, that should be the second check after checking if all 3 are blank

2) when using things like <= a date or time - it treats blank cells as always being less than. So change/add one more check within your `AND` function to check that the length of it is greater than 0 so make sure there is a valid value in there.

Comment: Yes you were right, one of my operations was wrong and rearranged as to which statements override. The most important was the LEN function as I just realised dates are stored as numbers and a blank as you have said, would make the operation fail. Thank you so much, I was stuck in this conundrum for ages.